# Reuse mock declaration across tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'd like to reuse mock declarations accross tests (if possible). 
Here is a minimal non-working example using ScalaTest and Mockito. I'm expecting the ​*yes*​ value in the first test but I get the ​*other*​ value.

It seems that the latest `Mockito.when` is the one applied for all test clauses.

Is there a way to avoid declaring mocks in each `in` clause?

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}
​
class ReuseMocksSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar {

  "A test" when {
    val service = mock[Service]
    "sharing mocks among tests" should {
      when(service.getVal).thenReturn("yes")
      "get yes value" in {
        service.getVal should be("yes")
      }
    }
    "sharing mocks among other tests" should {
      when(service.getVal).thenReturn("other")
      "get other value" in {
        service.getVal should be("other")
      }
    }
  }
​
  trait Service {
    def getVal: String
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the way I designed it and am now using a function to build my mocks:

```
def withValue(value: String)(body: (Service => String)) = {
  val service = mock[Service]
  when(service.getVal).thenReturn(value)
  body(service)
}
```

The test class would become:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class ReuseMocksSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar {

  "A test" when {
    "sharing mocks among tests" should {
      "get yes value" in {
        val value = withValue("yes") { service =>
          service.getVal
        }
        value should be("yes")
      }
    }
    "sharing mocks among other tests" should {
      "get other value" in {
        val value = withValue("other") { service =>
          service.getVal
        }
        value should be("other")
      }
    }
  }

  def withValue(value: String)(body: (Service => String)) = {
    val service = mock[Service]
    when(service.getVal).thenReturn(value)
    body(service)
  }

  trait Service {
    def getVal: String
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's the cleanest and easiest way to do it but it works...